# How to add CMake target compilation flag only if the flag is supported?

Tags: cmake

My current attempt at this includes the following:

```
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-pedantic" SUPPORTS_PEDANTIC)
if (SUPPORTS_PEDANTIC)
  target_compile_options ( some_target PRIVATE -pedantic )
endif()
```

Is there a function with equivalent functionality, like this?

```
target_compile_options_if_supported ( some_target PRIVATE -pedantic )
```

I am wondering if there is already a standard way to do this, other than writing my own function.

Comment: Hi, for me at the first sight, I think you can only do it by checking compilers capabilities with compilerVersion, or modifying Cmake's source code

If you want more precisions about the first answer I'll be pleased to add an answer. 
Just want to know if someone have a better idea.

Comment: If only `GCC` supports the `-pedantic` flag then you can check for the compiler and then do `if..else` on that.

Comment: @AmitSingh I want to avoid that for the sake of portability (what if other compilers support the option in the future...).

Comment: Also, `-pedantic` is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

As of today with cmake 3.24, nothing in the docs for [the `CheckCXXCompilerFlag` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXCompilerFlag.html#checkcxxcompilerflag) or [the `CheckCCompileFlag` module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCCompilerFlag.html#checkccompilerflag) docs document that such a function exists. Just write your own. It's simple and short. (Opinion) I don't personally think there's tons of merit for CMake to provide such functions since they'd have to make one for each kind of possible thing you might want to do with the result of the check.